# A more functional alternative to array2D in F#

Tags: f#, functional-programming

In F# array2Ds are mutable which doesn't make for the most functional code. At the moment, I'm hiding this by doing a Array2D.copy of my inputs when I want to make a change and return the array. i.e.

```
let test (x : int[,]) =
    let y = Array2D.copy x
    y.[0,0] <- 3
```

Is there a better approach that makes test more functional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use high-order functions on [Array2D module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353794.aspx) to work with `Array2D` in a functional style. Particularly, [Array2D.mapi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353734.aspx) operating on array indices is suitable for this task:

```
let test (xs: int[,]) =
   xs |> Array2D.mapi (fun i j x -> if i=0 && j=0 then 3 else x)
```

**EDIT:**

Generally speaking, your `test` function is fine since you can limit side effects inside the function only. You need to be more careful in the case of nested arrays; however, writing your own functions with controlled side effects usually gives better performance than using high-order functions for `Array2D`.